# PyTorch mat1 and mat2 shapes cannot be multiplied (4x460800 and 80000x16)

Tags: python, csv, deep-learning, pytorch, conv-neural-network

I'm trying to find road lanes using PyTorch. I created dataset and my model. But when I try to train my model, I get `mat1 and mat2 shapes cannot be multiplied (4x460800 and 80000x16)` error. I've tried other topic's solutions but those solutions didn't help me very much.

My dataset is bunch of road images with their validation images. I have .csv file that contains names of images (such as 'image1.jpg, image2.jpg'). Original size of images and validation images is 1280x720. I convert them 200x200 in my dataset code.

Road image:
[image]

Validation image:
[image]

Here's my dataset:

```
import os
import pandas as pd
import random

import torch
import torchvision.transforms.functional as TF
from torch.utils.data import Dataset
from torchvision import transforms
from PIL import Image

class Dataset(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, csv_file, root_dir, val_dir, transform=None):
        self.annotations = pd.read_csv(csv_file)
        self.root_dir = root_dir
        self.val_dir = val_dir
        self.transform = transform

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.annotations)

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        img_path = os.path.join(self.root_dir, self.annotations.iloc[index, 0])
        image = Image.open(img_path).convert('RGB')
        mask_path = os.path.join(self.val_dir, self.annotations.iloc[index, 0])
        mask = Image.open(mask_path).convert('RGB')

        transform = transforms.Compose([
            transforms.Resize((200, 200)), 
            transforms.ToTensor()
        ])

        if self.transform:
            image = self.transform(image)
            mask = self.transform(mask)

        return image, mask
```

My model:

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn

class Net(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.cnn_layers = nn.Sequential(
            # Conv2d, 3 inputs, 128 outputs
            # 200x200 image size
            nn.Conv2d(3, 128, kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=1),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2, stride=2),
            # Conv2d, 128 inputs, 64 outputs
            # 100x100 image size
            nn.Conv2d(128, 64, kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=1),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2, stride=2),
            # Conv2d, 64 inputs, 32 outputs
            # 50x50 image size
            nn.Conv2d(64, 32, kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=1),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2, stride=2)
        )

        self.linear_layers = nn.Sequential(
            # Linear, 32*50*50 inputs, 16 outputs
            nn.Linear(32 * 50 * 50, 16),
            # Linear, 16 inputs, 3 outputs
            nn.Linear(16, 3)
        )


    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.cnn_layers(x)
        x = x.view(x.size(0), -1)
        x = self.linear_layers(x)
        return x
```

How to avoid this error and train my images on these validation images?

Comment: Welp, it look like the `nn.Linear(32 * 50 * 50, 16)` cause this, U need trying to replace that line with `nn.Linear(32 * 50 * 50 * 4, 4)`

Comment: Now I'm getting `mat1 and mat2 shapes cannot be multiplied (4x460800 and 320000x4)` error. I think I have problem in these shapes but I couldn't figure out what should shapes would be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The answer:** In your case, NN input has a shape `(3, 1280, 720)`, not `(3, 200, 200)` as you want. Probably you have forgotten to modify `transform` argument in `RNetDataset`. It stays `None`, so transforms are not applied and the image is not resized. Another possibility is that it happens due to these lines:

```
        transform = transforms.Compose([
            transforms.Resize((200, 200)), 
            transforms.ToTensor()
        ])

        if self.transform:
            image = self.transform(image)
            mask = self.transform(mask)
```

You have two variables named `transform`, but one with `self.` - maybe you messed them up. Verify it and the problem should go away.

**How I came up with it:** `460800` is clearly a tensor size after reshaping before linear layers. According to the architecture, tensor processed with `self.cnn_layers` should have 32 layers, so its height multiplied by width should give `460800 / 32 = 14400`. Suppose that its height = `H`, width = `W`, so `H x W = 14400`. Let's understand, what was the original input size in this case? `nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2, stride=2)` layer divides height and width by 2, and it happens three times. So, the original input size has been `8H x 8W = 64 x 14400 = 936000`. Finally, notice that `936000 = 1280 * 720`. This can't be a magical coincidence. Case closed!

**Another suggestion:** even if you apply transforms correctly, your code might not work. Suppose that you have an input of size `(4, 3, 200, 200)`, where 4 is a batch size. Layers in your architecture will process this input as follows:

```
nn.Conv2d(3, 128, kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=1) # -> (4, 128, 200, 200)
nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2, stride=2) # -> (4, 128, 100, 100)
nn.Conv2d(128, 64, kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=1) # -> (4, 64, 100, 100)
nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2, stride=2) # -> (4, 64, 50, 50)
nn.Conv2d(64, 32, kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=1) # -> (4, 32, 50, 50)
nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2, stride=2) # -> (4, 32, 25, 25)
```

So, your first layer in `self.linear_layers` should be not `nn.Linear(32 * 50 * 50, 16)`, but `nn.Linear(32 * 25 * 25, 16)`. With this change, everything should be fine.

Comment: I accepted your solution as correct solution. I guess I had an error with transforms as you said. I fixed it. Changed my first layer of linear layers to `nn.Linear(32*25*25, 16)`. But now I'm getting `UserWarning: Using a target size (torch.Size([4, 3, 200, 200])) that is different to the input size (torch.Size([4, 3])). This will likely lead to incorrect results due to broadcasting. Please ensure they have the same size.` I changed my loss function to `MSELoss`